# Child selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having some issues to solve this problem with css selector. I need to select:

```
<li>
<a href="#">Asked to you</a>
</li>
```

using nth-child selectors, but I don't have the ability to add classes. Do you have any idea how I can make this work? After I choose this element with nth-child I need to add:before pseudo selector to it.

I have this code

```
<div class="userAccountNavigation"> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 small-3 column userProfileImage">
        <img src="#" alt="" class="profile-image">
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 small-9 column">
        <ul class="side-nav">
          <li>
             <a href="#">Profile</a>        
          </li>
          <li id="editProfile">
             <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-6 columns">
        <ul class="side-nav">
          <li>
             <a href="#">Activity Feed</a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="#">Asked to you</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
             <a href="#">Following</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 small-6 columns">
        <ul class="side-nav">
          <li class="">
             <a href="#">Questions</a>
             <span class="total">1</span>
          </li>
          <li class="">
             <a href="#">Answers</a>
             <span class="total">0</span>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to my problem. Thanks for checking anyway.

```
.userAccountNavigation div:nth-of-type(2) ul li:nth-child(2):before {
content: 'x';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example this should work.

```
.userAccountNavigation .row:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)::before{
  content: "->";
}
```

https://codepen.io/Pamz/pen/wEqLgw